# Subdomains for redirection only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

My domain is `meeting.com`.

I work with PHP, jQuery, for the main part. No ASP.

When a user creates an account, I'd like a subdomain `user.meeting.com` to be created for REDIRECTION purposes only. I don't want the subdomain to exist for real.

When someone would load `john13.meeting.com`, I would like the website to redirect to `meeting.com?user=john13` (I don't care if `john13.meeting.com` remains in the URL bar).

What is the most efficient and easy method of doing it automatically in PHP or Apache? Please consider performance too since I have many users.

Comment: [Wildcard Catch-all Subdomains](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains).

Comment: Wouldn't this (usually) be handled by Apache `.htaccess`?

Comment: @JarredFarrish I don't care if it's in .htaccess, all I want is to know how to do it efficiently and simply. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need PHP for that. The right Apache configuration with the [rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) on, will do the trick.

For example (not tested):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.meeting\.com?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.meeting\.com?$
RewriteRule ^$ /user/%1 [L]
```

Or if you're not rewriting further for SEO, the rule could be

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?user=%1 [L]
```

For more inspiration, check out the link Shef posted with [another example](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains) of how to achieve this.

Comment: I would have thought this would be a `Redirect` style of rewrite, although I suppose the question leaves that open for discussion.

Comment: What do you mean with that, why should it be a redirect? A redirect would mean that the subdomains once existed and the content has moved. That's not what you want, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but what I mean is that the browser is pointed to another resource, instead of it being rewritten on the server only and the user never knows. My initial thought was it would be a redirect (like using `header('Location:)`), and not a transparent rewrite, but I'm not sure what the OP really wants/needs.

Comment: @markus Is there a way to allow the server to process the URL in PHP? For instance, if I wish to convert the username to it's matching ID in my SQL db, I couldn't do it with the htaccess file. If I can't I'll find a way to rewrite my code in order to fit it to the method you proposed.

Comment: @Jared Farrish I just want the fake subdomain to be redirected to the main domain with the appropriate GET variables.

Comment: @Adam - Then I think you want a redirect and not necessarily a rewrite.

Comment: By the way, I saw people doing this redirection trick using only 404 not found page (the 404 page script doing the redirection job), but my first thought is that it isn't good in terms of performance.